# nodejs getting double of records from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Product = require('../models/products');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var products = Product.find();
  res.render('shops/index', { title: 'Express' ,Product:products});
});

module.exports = router;
```

i am new to nodejs and mongodb .I have 5 record in database but the code above is returning 15 records from database

here is the model implemented

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var schema = new Schema({
    imagePath:{type: String,required:true},
    title:{type: String,required:true},
    description:{type: String,required:true},
    price:{type: String,required:true},

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product',schema);
```

Comment: this code shouldn't get you anything relevant because Product.find is an asynchronous operation where the result is provided via a callback. Are you using mongoose or how is your model implemented?

Comment: @giggo1604 i m using mongoose

Comment: @giggo1604 see the edited version for model code

Comment: You shouldn't be getting 15 of those. Can you show us how are you making connection with mongoDB?

Comment: @LazarNikolic mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/shopping', { useNewUrlParser: true });

Comment: you have to call it like that `Product.find({}, function(err, products) () {
    res.json(products);
});`

Comment: Are you sure you are getting that 15 records from the database? have you tried logging it? I have an assumption that it was called 3 times and thus makes it 5 on first call 10 on 2nd call and 15 on the third... You need to show us more of how it was implemented...

Comment: You haven't posted the relation between result on your homepage and values in your database! Are they duplicate, are they some alien values from mars.

Answer (score 0):

find is an asynchronous operation where the result is provided in a callback function. Querying for it would look like that:

```
Product.find({}, function(err, products) () {
    res.json(products);
});
```

But i can't see why you are getting 15 results...